# UIWebView window.innerWidth=0

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, frameset

I have two simple html files which shows in my app in UIWebView, its code:
index.html

```
 <script>
        var iWinWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var iWinHeight = window.innerHeight;

        alert(window.name + "\n iWinWidth="+iWinWidth+" iWinHeight="+iWinHeight);
</script>
 <FRAMESET rows="704,..." cols="1024,...">
 <FRAME SRC="2.html" name="contentFrame" noresize>
 </FRAMESET>
```

and 2.html:

```
<html> 
<body>

<script>        
            var iWinWidth = window.innerWidth; 
    var iWinHeight = window.innerHeight;

        alert(window.name + "\n iWinWidth="+iWinWidth+" iWinHeight="+iWinHeight); </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

the problem is that in 2.html window.innerWidth and  window.innerHeight are 0 very often. What can I do to solve this? This code is small sample for testing and solving problem in big program, 2.html like files is third party, I can change index.html or inject javascript into 2.html, but not change its own scripts cause I don't know its

Loading file in obj-c:

```
documentPath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testFormats" ofType:@""] stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentPath];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentPath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView  loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your script above the body tag in 2.html and triggering the window size function when you get body onLoad.